# Unable to deserialize a JSON response from SonarQube using the gson library

Tags: java, sonarqube, gson

I'm trying to use gson to deserialize some data that I'm getting back from a SonarQube API on various code metrics. This is an example of the raw JSON coming back from the server:

```
{
  "component": {
    "id": "c5fc9d6k-e28b-4ea0-8922-df18c7e07ac1",
    "key": "APP:master",
    "name": "master",
    "qualifier": "TRK",
    "measures": [
      {
        "metric": "coverage",
        "value": "19.9",
        "periods": [
          {
            "index": 1,
            "value": "0.09999999999999787"
          },
          {
            "index": 2,
            "value": "0.09999999999999787"
          },
          {
            "index": 3,
            "value": "0.6999999999999993"
          },
          {
            "index": 4,
            "value": "8.7"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "metric": "overall_coverage",
        "value": "55.7",
        "periods": [
          {
            "index": 1,
            "value": "0.0"
          },
          {
            "index": 2,
            "value": "0.0"
          },
          {
            "index": 3,
            "value": "3.0"
          },
          {
            "index": 4,
            "value": "55.7"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "metric": "ncloc",
        "value": "1089127",
        "periods": [
          {
            "index": 1,
            "value": "3835"
          },
          {
            "index": 2,
            "value": "3835"
          },
          {
            "index": 3,
            "value": "-74350"
          },
          {
            "index": 4,
            "value": "102501"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm attempting to deserialize it into a Component class with this code:

```
public Component getComponentMeasures(String componentKey, List<String> measures) throws ClientProtocolException,
        IOException, JsonSyntaxException, UnsupportedOperationException, JSONException 
{
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(baseURL + String.format("/api/measures/component?componentKey=%s&metricKeys=%s",
            componentKey, StringUtils.join(measures, ",")));

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String componenta = getJSONResponse(response);
    System.out.print(componenta);
    Component component = gson.fromJson(componenta, Component.class);

    return component;
}
```

This is the Component class that I'm deserializing it into:

```
public class Component {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("key")
    @Expose
    private String key;

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("qualifier")
    @Expose
    private String qualifier;

    @SerializedName("path")
    @Expose
    private String path;

    @SerializedName("measures")
    @Expose
    private Measure[] measures = null;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getQualifier() {
        return qualifier;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public Measure[] getMeasures() {
        return measures;
    }

}
```

This Component class also contains an array of Measures which in turn contain an array of periods.

Measure Class:

```
public class Measure {

    @SerializedName("metric")
    @Expose
    private String metric;

    @SerializedName("value")
    @Expose
    private String value;

    @SerializedName("periods")
    @Expose
    private Period[] periods = null;

    public String getMetric() {
        return metric;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Period[] getPeriods() {
        return periods;
    }

}
```

Period class:
    public class Period {

```
    @SerializedName("index")
    @Expose
    private Integer index;
    @SerializedName("value")
    @Expose
    private String value;

    public Integer getIndex() {
    return index;
    }

    public String getValue() {
    return value;
    }

}
```

When I run this code, the deserialized component is null. Any ideas on anything that I may be doing wrong here? Note that there is an extra parameter in the Component class, "path", that is null in the JSON. This is optional and exists in other classes which contain a collection of Component objects. In those cases, this Component object and JSON deserialize fine. I've compared the JSON side-by-side and they are identical. I only seem to have the issue when trying to deserialize a standalone component object. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your JSON document is a JSON object with a single property (the path: `$.component`) with a *nested* component, however you're trying to deserialize it as if it were the top-most object:

```java
Component component = gson.fromJson(componenta, Component.class);
```

Just create another class to match the top-most single property object, say something like:

```java
final class Response {

    @SerializedName("component")
    @Expose
    final Component component = null;

}
```

And then sample code like

```java
final Response response = gson.fromJson(componenta, Response.class);
for ( final Measure measure : response.component.measures ) {
    System.out.println(measure.metric + " " + measure.value);
}
```

will print the following output:

> coverage 19.9
>   overall_coverage 55.7
>   ncloc 1089127

Answer (score -1):

Sonar has an SDK for their API that encapsulates all of this and you don't have to create your own classes, etc. I used it to get info out like you're doing. See https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Using+the+Web+Service+Java+client and my use of it: http://myvogonpoetry.com/wp/2013/02/21/using-the-sonar-rest-api-for-weekly-emails/

Comment: You've pointed to the docs for 4.5, a by-now very old version. Further, that client is deprecated.